# NDK is already installed but I got this error in react native cli

Tags: android, react-native, android-ndk, react-native-reanimated, mobli

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
[CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 did not have a source.properties file
[CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 did not have a source.properties file

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> NDK is not installed

what should I do? I only run one project and another projects are always facing these eror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set `ndk version` in `build.gradle` file

```
android {
        ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
    }
```